# Angular 6 - Allow user to access page without being logged in

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I want to redirect to login page if user is not logged in. Example: localhost:4200, localhost:4200/pages/login and any other url the user provides. However, if the user accesses the url localhost:4200/pages/register, they must be redirected to the registration page, without the user being logged in. In other words, this register page must be available to anyone. But in my current code, it's not working, when I type localhost:4200/pages/register, it is automatically redirected to localhost:4200/pages/login.

These are the structure:

```
>app
>>pages
  >>> login
  >>> register
```

app-routing.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
// Layouts
import {FullLayoutComponent} from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import {SimpleLayoutComponent} from './layouts/simple-layout.component';
import {SmallLayoutComponent} from './layouts/small-layout.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'inicio',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './layouts/home/home.module#HomeModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'cns',
        loadChildren: './components/cns/cns.module#CnsModule'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'pages',
    component: SimpleLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Pages'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
      }
    ]
  },

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

pages-module-routing.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {P404Component} from './404.component';
import {P500Component} from './500.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'Example Pages'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '404',
        component: P404Component,
        data: {
          title: 'Page 404'
        }
      },
      {
        path: '500',
        component: P500Component,
        data: {
          title: 'Page 500'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Login Page'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'Register Page'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Where does the redirect happen? Within the SimpleLayoutComponent? If so, change that. Such redirects should happen within a RouteGuard (https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). You can then attach this route guard to every route you want to protect and do not add it to the register route

Comment: As the previous commenter mentioned, this should be handled in a guard. I don't see any guards. Do you have logic in a component somewhere that is doing the redirect currently?